# Regex for extracting only the Youtube Embedment URL in Angular 5

Tags: regex

I think it is not very convenient for an user the get this link here:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/GmvM6syadl0
```

Because YouTube provides an entire code snipped like so:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GmvM6syadl0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It would be a lot better if the user could take the code snippet above and my program is just going to extract the url for him.

Any ideas how to go about this? I'm usually not very good at extracting data from elaborate strings, what I would like to end up with is something like this:

```
let yTLink = extractYoutubeLinkfromIframe(providedInput);

extractYoutubeLinkfromIframe(iframeTag) {
    // do fancy regex stuff
}
```

Comment: Using regex you could use [src=".*?(?=")](https://regex101.com/r/nYMdCK/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will have a format like that iFrame you could use split and I did it using the follwoing code:

```
extractYoutubeLinkfromIframe(iframeTag) {
    let youtubeUrl = iframeTag.split('src');
    youtubeUrl = youtubeUrl[1].split('"');
    return youtubeUrl[1];
}
```

First we split by the src, so, we will separte the iFrame string, after that, we split by quote ", to get just the part that we need as the link is with "[link]", we get the first position that will indicate that we want to get the link.

Comment: thanks a lot, I hade hoped for regex but this is good as well :)